# find which object called function

Tags: javascript, html

If I have multiple objects with different IDs but they all call the same function when clicked. Is there any way to track or find which object called the function.

e.g

```
function test(){
    /*function changes background color of 'div' and displays the id of the object that called the function*/

        document.getElementById('div').style.backgroundColor = 'red';

        var objectID = /*WHATEVER OBJECT CALLED FUNCTION*/;

        document.getElementById('textbox').innerHTML = objectID;
    }
```

cheers

Comment: did you know you can pass arguments to a function? `function test(id)` then when you call the function like `test('someid')` then `id` will be `'someid'`

Comment: Thank you, that will work! That's annoyingly simple haha.

Comment: of course, depending on *how* test is called, it could be simpler, but you haven't shown that very important piece of the puzzle :p

Answer (score 1):

If you're using

```
onclick="test()"
```

in the element, change it so that it passes itself to the function:

```
onclick="test(this)"
```

Then the function receives the object as the argument.

```
function test(element) {
    var objectID = element.id;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
function test(id) {

    document.getElementById('div').style.backgroundColor = 'red';

    var objectID = id;

    document.getElementById('textbox').innerHTML = objectID;
}

var object = {

    id = "AnObject",
    testFunction: function() {
        test(this.id);
    }

};

object.testFunction();
```